# How do I know which version of SBT I am running?

Tags: sbt

When I run the `version` command in the sbt console it shows "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT". Is this the current sbt version?

I'm used the [Getting Started](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Setup) guide on the SBT wiki to install sbt on my system.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8461013/1305344 (although the title of this question turns out to be better).

Answer (score 13):

The `version` command prints the version of the project you are building. You probably want `sbt-version`.

Comment: As of sbt 1.0, needs to be `sbt sbtVersion`.  Hyphenated commands not supported  anymore.  (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html)

Answer (score 5):

To check version of the sbt that you are using:

```
$ sbt sbt-version
```

Comment: This is not true, it shows the version of sbt that is specified in the project, not the sbt version that is running.