# How can I check the SBT version?

Tags: sbt

How do I check which version of SBT I'm running?

I have the Bash file set up that uses `sbt-launch.jar`, and it works, but

```
sbt version
```

only shows the "project version" (0.1) and

```
sbt --version
```

does nothing.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

```
sbt --version
```

It now works as of version 1.3.3+ (credit to [@ElectronWill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71310306/1129420)).

You may also want to use `sbt about` that (copying [Mark Harrah's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461013/how-to-check-sbt-version?rq=1#comment10562645_8462854)):

> The about command was added recently to try to succinctly print the
> most relevant information, including the sbt version.

Comment: Could a --version command line flag be considered? It's the thing people will try first.

Comment: @MattR Could not agree more with you... It's curious why that wasn't the first thought of the sbt author(s).

Comment: is there any way to set the different sbt versions for the different **subprojects**?

Comment: The question was "How do I check which version of sbt I'm **running**?" and the answer is about pringting version of **current project**. Why answer is acepted?

Comment: Trust SBT to always choose the most non-standard way of doing things :)

Comment: HAHA this is just hilarious

Comment: The whole world uses '--version', sbt uses 'sbtVersion'. I have to check it every single time when I need it (not frequently).

Comment: Obtuse and well stashed in the documentation, following good old sbt tradition.

Comment: If they cared about being user friendly they wouldn't have made a new DSL just for compiling

Comment: I spent half hour on how to get a version # for sbt.. LOL..  I use sbt -h, and did not see any '-version'  or '-- V' and wondering how to get a version for my sbt...   LOL.. 'sbtVersion'

Comment: Provided your build.sbt compiles. It's like making Java --version dependent on whether your .java files compile.

Comment: `sbt` is ridiculous, everybody hate it.

Comment: `sbt sbtVersion` then `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: I just have to leave this here ... https://www.acronymfinder.com/Sucks-Big-Time-(SBT).html

Answer (score 38):

Type "sbt about" and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the SBT version:

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Running the command, "sbt sbt-version" will simply output your current directory and the version number.

```
$ sbt sbt-version
[info] Set current project to spark (in build file:/home/morgan/code/spark/)
[info] 0.13.8
```

Comment: Starting with sbt 1.0 you even *have* to use `sbt sbtVersion` (camelCase) as support for [hyphen-separated names has been dropped](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html).

Answer (score 16):

In SBT 0.13 and above, you can use the `sbtVersion` task (as pointed out by @steffen) or `about` command (as pointed out by @mark-harrah)

There's a difference how the `sbtVersion` task works in and outside a SBT project. When in a SBT project, `sbtVersion` displays the version of SBT used by the project and its subprojects.

```
$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/project
[info] Set current project to scalania (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
[info] exercises/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.1-RC5
[info] scalania/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.1-RC5
```

It's set in `project/build.properties`:

```
jacek:~/oss/scalania
$ cat project/build.properties
sbt.version=0.13.1-RC5
```

The same task executed outside a SBT project shows the current version of the executable itself.

```
jacek:~
$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to jacek (in build file:/Users/jacek/)
[info] 0.13.0
```

When you're outside, the `about` command seems to be a better fit as it shows the sbt version as well as Scala's and available plugins.

```
jacek:~
$ sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to jacek (in build file:/Users/jacek/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/}jacek 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.2
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.2
```

You may want to run 'help about' to read its documentation:

```
jacek:~
$ sbt 'help about'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to jacek (in build file:/Users/jacek/)
Displays basic information about sbt and the build.
```

For the `sbtVersion` setting, the `inspect` command can help.

```
$ sbt 'inspect sbtVersion'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to jacek (in build file:/Users/jacek/)
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 0.13.0
[info] Description:
[info]  Provides the version of sbt.  This setting should be not be modified.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:sbtVersion
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:67
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:sbtVersion
[info]  {.}/*:sbtVersion
[info]  */*:sbtVersion
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:sbtVersion
```

The `version` setting that people seem to expect to inspect to know the SBT version is to set *The version/revision of the current module*.

```
$ sbt 'inspect version'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to jacek (in build file:/Users/jacek/)
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] Description:
[info]  The version/revision of the current module.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:version
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:102
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:projectId
[info]  *:isSnapshot
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:version
[info]  {.}/*:version
[info]  */*:version
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:version
```

When used in a SBT project the tasks/settings may show different outputs.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a custom sbt launcher, such as sbt-extras, that overrides the meaning of `sbt-version` one the command line.  Otherwise, I don't know of a difference between `sbt-version` at the command line and at the prompt.  It should be the same `sbtVersion` setting in both cases.

Comment: is there any way to set the different sbt versions for the different subprojects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825539/specify-the-version-of-sbt-for-a-subproject

Comment: Why does `sbt sbtVersion` run outside a project take 9 seconds to run?  Python, node and ruby all take under a second, as do awk, sed, minibloom and a bunch of other command line tools.  gcc takes one whole second, which is super-slow.  But 9 seconds takes the cherry. 
 What is sbt doing in that time?

Comment: @MaxMurphy JVM initialization is among the slowest things I think.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `sbt about`

```
Example: 
    C:\Users\smala>sbt about
    [info] Set current project to smala (in build file:/C:/Users/smala/)
    [info] This is sbt 0.13.6
    [info] The current project is {file:/C:/Users/smala/}smala 0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
    [info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin,   sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
    [info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4"
```

Comment: For others who are seeking the answer to this question, THIS is the answer.  Cannot understand why the erroneous answer above was accepted... by digging through the disucssion, one can find this answer... but...

Answer (score 6):

Recent versions of SBT finally support a standard `--version` flag!

```
$ sbt --version

sbt version in this project:    1.6.2
sbt script version: 1.6.2
```

(tested with 1.6+, but it seems that [it has existed since at least 1.3.3](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.3.3))

Answer (score 3):

From within the sbt shell

```
sbt:venkat> about
[info] This is sbt 1.3.3
...
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you run `sbt` from the command line might have changed a bit over the 9 years since the question was originally posted.

Today, you will always be interacting with at least two "versions":

- the launcher script (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/sbt`) version.<sup>[1]</sup> Check with `sbt --script-version`.
- the default SBT version (=sbt-launcher JAR version), decided primarily by the project SBT version (in `project/build.properties`), secondarily by the launcher script itself. Check with `sbt --script-version` (or `sbtVersion` in the SBT shell)

Fortunately, in most day-to-day scenarios, the project SBT version is the only one that you need to be aware of.

---

<sup>1
<sub>It used to be just `java -jar sbt-launcher.jar`, *then* there was/is `sbt-extras/sbt` (aka "rebel cut"), then there was the "official" `sbt` script but in a separate github project called `sbt-launcher-packaging` (now archived). Today, the default script sits in the root folder of the `sbt/sbt` GH project and is generally the only version you need to worry about.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

Run the SBT console and then type `sbtVersion` to check the SBT version, and `scalaVersion` for the Scala runtime version.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `sbt sbt-version` led to some error as

```
[error] Not a valid command: sbt-version (similar: writeSbtVersion, session)
[error] Not a valid project ID: sbt-version
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: sbt-version (similar: sbtVersion, version, sbtBinaryVersion)
[error] sbt-version
[error]            ^
```

As you can see the hint `similar: sbtVersion, version, sbtBinaryVersion`, all of them work but the correct one is generated by `sbt sbtVersion`

Comment: The newer versions the following works,  sbt about  or sbt sbtVersion

Comment: There are already other answers for that I just wanted to include new information and not repeat other answers @viru